# how override appsetting values from docker in asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I made an asp.net core project,but i have question,how override app-setting values after container built?
my appsetting:

```
  "AppSetting": {
    "RabbitMqUrl": "rabbitmq://localhost/",
    "RabbitMqUserName": "guest",
    "RabbitMqPassword": "guest",
    "LoginMessage": "x",
    "ResetPasswordMessage": "x",
    "myval": 10
  }
```

I find this command but i  want see and change myval value when container is running in for example in restart container command,how do these items?

```
   docker run -it -p 5005:5005 -e "AppSetting:myval=123" identity
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: After some clearification, question is about changing environment vars run-time. That is not a very good idea. For sharing application-wide variables that may change, a cache is a viable solution.

In Startup#ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

Then you can inject

```
IMemoryCache
```

into your code. You can add/change cache value like this

```
_cache.Set("myval", 123, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
```

and the value will stay in cache until end of time (or until your code changes/removes it). You fetch data from cache like this

```
var myVal = 0;
if (_cache.TryGetValue("myval", out int value))
{
   myVal = value;
}
```

If you need to initialize the cache with some value from appsettings.json, that can be done inside Program#Main after webHost is built, and before calling webHost.Run / webHost.RunAsync.

END of update

---

Unless you have a class called AppSetting, json should look like below. You should have an appsettings.json that applies to all environments, an appsettings.Staging.json for staging, and an appsettings.Production.json for production.

```
{
  "RabbitMqUrl": "rabbitmq://localhost/",
  "RabbitMqUserName": "guest",
  "RabbitMqPassword": "guest",
  "LoginMessage": "x",
  "ResetPasswordMessage": "x",
  "myval": 10
}
```

You select running enviroment in Docker file like this

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
```

You can override parameters in appsettings.json like this

```
 ENV ASPNETCORE_myval 123
```

If you stick with your original JSON structure:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_AppSetting__myval 123
```

Comment: thanks roar, i want this value change in runtime or like this command    docker run -it -p 5005:5005 -e "AppSetting:myval=123" identity ,i dont want create new instanse from my image ,but  apply this change on current container.

Comment: @Ali.goodarzi: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. But you should not do it like that, settings are static stuff that is used for getting the app up-and-running. I will update my answer with more code.